# Access insert syntax from form using Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I have button that will inset data into access 2013 database on click event.

Is that the correct way to call data from access 2013 form textbox into insert statement ?

```
Private Sub EnterDataFrom_Click()


CurrentDb.Execute "insert into Employee_info" _
                        & "(First_Name,Father_Name,Last_Name,Mother_Name,birthda0te,Birthplace,Gender,Military_Service,Marital_status,Nationality,National_ID,PhoneNum,EM_phoneNum,Mobile,E-Mail)" _
                        & "values (me.First_Name,me.Father_Name,me.Last_Name,me.Mother_Name,me.birthdate,me.Birthplace,me.Gender,me.Military_Service,me.Marital_status,me.Nationality,me.National_ID,me.PhoneNum,me.EM_phoneNum,me.Mobile,me.E-Mail);"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Xipooo is right. 
Generally, it is possible to wrap your value entries in between apostrophes at all time.

The reason why your button might not work is that you forgot empty spaces before your line breaks (behind Employee_info and the closing bracket behind the fields) :

`CurrentDb.Execute "insert into Employee_info " _ & "(First_Name,Father_Name,Last_Name,Mother_Name,birthda0te,Birthplace,Gender,Military_Service,Marital_status,Nationality,National_ID,PhoneNum,EM_phoneNum,Mobile,E-Mail) " _
& "values('" & me.First_Name & "', '" & me.Father_Name & "', '" & me.Last_Name & "', '" & me.Mother_Name & "', '" & me.birthdate & "', '" & me.Birthplace & "', '" & me.Gender & "', " & me.Military_Service &", '" & me.Marital_status & "', '" & me.Nationality & "', " & me.National_ID & "', '" & me.PhoneNum & "', '" & me.EM_phoneNum & "', '" & me.Mobile & "', '" & me.E-Mail & "');"`

(based on Xipooo's previous answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not properly formatted to collect the values form the form.  You need to get the values outside of the string and concatenate them.  Additionally string values that are being inserted into text columns should be wrapped in apostrophe's if they are inside of a string variable.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into Employee_info" _
& "(First_Name,Father_Name,Last_Name,Mother_Name,birthda0te,Birthplace,Gender,Military_Service,Marital_status,Nationality,National_ID,PhoneNum,EM_phoneNum,Mobile,E-Mail)" _
& "values('" & me.First_Name & "', '" & me.Father_Name & "', '" & me.Last_Name & "', '" & me.Mother_Name & "', '" & me.birthdate & "', '" & me.Birthplace & "', '" & me.Gender & "', " & me.Military_Service &", '" & me.Marital_status & "', '" & me.Nationality & "', " & me.National_ID & "', '" & me.PhoneNum & "', '" & me.EM_phoneNum & "', '" & me.Mobile & "', '" & me.E-Mail & "');"
```

I am assuming here that Military_Service and National_ID are numerical columns.